# Why does mysql escape break the entire query?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, syntax-error

I've been trying to find issue in this query and can't seem to find it, it's driving me insane. Here is my code:

```
sql.query("INSERT INTO coinflips (host,host_side,items,join,expires,value,secret,hash,winningPercentage) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",[" "," "," "," "," ",0," "," ",0.5],(err)=>{
        if(err) return console.log(err);
});
```

However,  I get the following error:

`'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'join,expires,value,secret,hash,winningPercentage) VALUES (\' \',\' \',\' \',\' \',\' \',0,\' at line 1'`

Here is the database:

https://ibb.co/LdywXQN

I've never had issues with escaping queries but suddenly this one stopped working, I do not understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`join` is a reserved word, you have to escape it using backticks:

```
sql.query("INSERT INTO coinflips (host,host_side,items,`join`,expires,value,secret,hash,winningPercentage) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",[" "," "," "," "," ",0," "," ",0.5],(err)=>{
    // Here -------------------------------------------^----^
    if(err) return console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: It's worth noting that MySQL's errors are exceedingly specific about where the problem is. Pay close attention to where it indicates with "near ..." because that's precisely where the problem is.